# WebDriverException selenium-python tests on CircleCi

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, pytest, circleci-2.0

I'm setting up python automation test using selenium and pytest, my goal is to run it on Circleci 2.0.

Locally tests are up and running, but this error occurs on CircleCi server, don't know why 
I tried to update project modules (but that wasn't the case)

```
    def test_setup(self):
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        options.add_argument('-headless')
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=options)
        self.driver.maximize_window()
        self.driver.get(self.url)
        yield
        self.driver.quit()
```

I run into following error's:

````
venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py:73: in __init__
    self.service.start()
venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py:98: in start
    self.assert_process_still_running()
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 

self = <selenium.webdriver.chrome.service.Service object at 0x7f52e8a66a90>

    def assert_process_still_running(self):
        return_code = self.process.poll()
        if return_code is not None:
            raise WebDriverException(
                'Service %s unexpectedly exited. Status code was: %s'
>               % (self.path, return_code)
            )
E           selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service /home/circleci/.wdm/chromedriver/75.0.3770.8/linux64/chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 127

venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py:111: WebDriverException
---------------------------- Captured stdout setup -----------------------------

Checking for linux64 chromedriver:75.0.3770.8 in cache
There is no cached driver. Downloading new one...
Trying to download new driver from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/75.0.3770.8/chromedriver_linux64.zip
Unpack archive /home/circleci/.wdm/chromedriver/75.0.3770.8/linux64/chromedriver.zip
________ ERROR at setup of TestExperiment.test_search_tutors_from_genf ```


>E selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: >Unable to find a matching set of capabilities

>venv/lib/python3.6/site->packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py:242: >SessionNotCreatedException
````

Answer (score 0):

Case-closed it's turn out that there was the problem with CircleCi configuration file. In order to run those test I was forced to install Chrome at docker img, by adding appropriate dependencies to the config.yml file.